# Angular runtime configuration not working with user manager creation (oidc client)

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am not an angular expert but I need this resolved so any help would be grateful.

We have built an angular app (using angular version 7.x).  As this app will be deployed globally I chose not to use environment.X.ts for our environment variables as I would have to build the app multiple times to be released.  Instead, I found an article that explained how to set up 'runtime' configuration via a JSON file that would be downloaded after the app was on the user's device.

Today we began integrating the oidc client but have run into an oddity.  When we try to access the runtime configuration to set up the user manager settings, we receive errors that the data is null.  This has struck us as odd because we are injecting this AppConfigureService in other parts without issue.  Has someone set up an angular app with the oidc client that uses a dynamically loaded configuration?

Below is some of the code we are currently using.

**app-config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadAppConfig() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/config/appConfig.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  }

  getConfig() : AppConfig {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}

export class AppConfig {
  auth_authority: string;
  auth_redirect_uri: string;
  auth_post_logout_redirect_uri: string;
  oc_api_url: string;
  comm_api_url: string;
}
```

**auth.service.ts**
*Some code omitted to save space*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';
import { fail } from 'assert';

import { AppConfigService, AppConfig } from '../services/app-config.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { debug } from 'util';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private appConfigService: AppConfigService = null;
  private manager: UserManager = null;
  private user: User = null;

  constructor(private appConfig: AppConfigService) {
    this.appConfigService = appConfig;
    this.appConfigService.loadAppConfig()
    .then(()=>{
      this.manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings(this.appConfigService.getConfig()))
      this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
        this.user = user;
      });
    });
.
.
.
  }
.
.
.
}

export function getClientSettings(appConfig: AppConfig): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority: appConfig.auth_authority,
    client_id: environment.auth_client_id,
    redirect_uri: appConfig.auth_redirect_uri,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: appConfig.auth_post_logout_redirect_uri,
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: environment.auth_scope,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
    //automaticSilentRenew: true,
    //silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
}
```